# RegexMatch Returns 'False', but Regex String Looks Correct

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

I'm attempting to match common email domains--but not company domains--in an email list, and I'm trying to use RegexMatch in Google Sheets (the regexmatch is part of a larger IF formula, but this part specifically isn't working).

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, but in the various Regex testing tools, the regular expression works as intended.

However, when the expression is part of the Google Sheets formula, it returns 'False' when it should have matched an email in the adjacent cell.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
=REGEXMATCH("INDIRECT(ADDRESS( ROW(),COLUMN()-1))","(\@aol\.com)|(\@live\.com)|(\@bellsouth\.net)|(\@btinternet\.com)|(\@ntlworld\.com)|(\@virgin\.net)|(\@ymail)|(\@att\.net)|(\@hotmail\.com)|(\@sbcglobal\.net)|(\@charter\.net)|(\@virginmedia\.com)|(\@o2\.co\.uk)|(\@wanadoo\.co\.uk)|(\@rambler\.ru)|(\@comcast\.net)|(\@hotmail\.co\.uk)|(\@verizon\.net)|(\@comcast\.net)|(\@blueyonder\.co\.uk)|(\@orange\.net)|(\@bt\.com)|(\@yandex\.ru)|(\@facebook\.com)|(\@mac\.com)|(\@yahoo\.com)|(\@cox\.net)|(\@freeserve\.co\.uk)|(\@sky\.com)|(\@ya\.ru)|(\@sbcglobal\.net)|(\@gmail\.com)|(\@me\.com)|(\@yahoo\.co\.uk)|(\@earthlink\.net)|(\@live\.co\.uk)|(\@talktalk\.co\.uk)|(\@list\.ru)|(\@optonline\.net)|(\@outlook\.com)|(\@juno\.com)|(\@tiscali\.co\.uk)|(\@icloud\.com)|(\@bell\.net)|(\@gmx\.com)|(\@mail\.com)|(\@googlemail\.com)|(\@msn\.com)")
```

Comment: Hmm, tried all of these, and it's still not working. I've even reduced it to "aol", and still can't get a match.

Comment: I've figured out that it has something to do with the INDIRECT function, and not necessarily the regex.

Comment: The problem is the quotations around the INDIRECT function.

Comment: The quotes weren't necessary around the INDIRECT function.

Comment: Glad you've solved it ..

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) to use indirect, you would need to remove the quotes around it otherwise it is treating as a literal string,

2) just  a note, it isn't mandatory to have a capture group around every variation, the `|` is already treating the values as potential matches.

If you have a long list of potential emails, what I usually do is list them all somewhere, lets pretend in column A, and then use `JOIN` and the `|` as the join delimiter to reference that list for your regexmatch.

If you do not plan on adding values to the list, then this should work:

```
=REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( ROW(),COLUMN()-1)),join("|",$A$1:$A$48))
```

However if you do in fact want a dynamic list length that you can continually build on, you can modify again to trim the range only to the length of values available:

```
=REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( ROW(),COLUMN()-1)),join("|",INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A:A))))
```

[image]